# Newbie: Slow Apache2 Response Time

Tags: server, apache2, php

As the title says I'm a newbie with this stuff but I'm willing to learn what I need to know. I'm simply ignorant atm. This is a Rackspace server with Ubuntu 15.10 running Apache2.

I have a PHP web app that runs with (not yet optimized) good load times on my local machine but stalls for about 2-4 seconds on page load/reload on the server. This seems to be an accumulating stall. The more time that passes (users logging in?) the slower it seems to get.

Things I've tried to troubleshoot and other information:

1. I've checked both Chrome network tools and pingdom.com and both reveal that the first initial request is where the longest wait, not local or external resources.
2. Restarting apache helps a little but running the stop then start command seem to temporarily increase load speeds. One thing I noticed here is that I start to get quite a few entries under "CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service" when I run the command "systemctl status apache2.service". I'm not sure if this should indicate anything to me or not.
3. I'm peaking at around 250m memory
4. Also, if it is pertinent, I am using nodejs, forever and socketio along side Laravel 5 though I don't think that any of this is the culprit for the long wait on the initial response.

What other reports or logs do I need to generate or look at to determine what might be the cause? I've heard some people having an issue with "resource leeching" and others with DDOS. How might I rule something like this out?

Here is a pingdom result of a faster load but still non-optimal. (I know, I need to bundle my scripts and styles ;) )
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/jl6bX/http://barkerbot.com/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try a lighter server like Lighttpd, maybe

Comment: I assume you're running against a database? What's the status on it? e.g. is it on the same machine? What kind of database software is it? This question is likely better suited to serverfault or stackoverflow, as this is likely not an ubuntu issue

Comment: @Musher Thank you for the recommendation as to where I should be posting this question. I see your point and appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes for performance issues, but for optimization in general i recommend using a Profiler. There is some discussion going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145373/what-are-some-good-php-profilers-that-can-be-used)

Personally i use XHProf/[XHGui](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui/) and did not try the others that much.